# terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread

Tags: ios, iphone, realm

am using Realm for my persistence. Now I really confused should i use realm or not.

I am using almofire ,ObjectMapper and Realm following is my code.

UserInfo

```
class UserInfo:Object,Mapper
{
 dynamic var name:String?
dynamic var accountTye:String?
dynamic var loginResult: String?
}
```

Once I get success response from server for my login.

=========
UserSessionManager

```
  var userInfo:UserInfo?

 UserSessionManager.shared().saveSession()
  func saveSession()
  {
  RealmHelper.shared().save(userInfo!)
  }
```

RealmHelper

```
   func save<T:Object>(_ realmObject:T) {
   let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: ".realm", qos:        .background)
   backgroundQueue.async {
   let realm = try! Realm()
    debugPrint("Realm Creation (Thread.current)") I am getting same    thread
    if realm.isInWriteTransaction{
    return
   }
  try! realm.write {
  debugPrint("Realm add (Thread.current)") I am getting same thread
  realm.add(realmObject)
  }
  }

  }
```

When I am trying to accessing UserSessionManager.shared().userInfo object I am getting this crash.

I did not understand why it is happening.

Comment: I do read them but I am getting this error weirdly when I am not accessing Realm.

Comment: I am getting this error while accessing the model object which is meant to save in the Realm , which is weird

Comment: UserInfo *is* a realm object. So you are accessing realm when you access UserIinfo.

Comment: How can I access userInfo then ?

Comment: Add more of your code showing where and how to create and instantiate a UserInfo

Comment: I have fixed it the way i was accessing the object let me know if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by accessing the object UserInfo from Realm.
The problem is I am adding realm object(UserInfo) into Realm.

I am trying to access the same object which is stored in another singleton class directly which is causing me the issue.

Now I am accessing the same object after retriving from realm , now no issues,

But I don't is it the way to access Realm object once we added it to Realm.